# How to load image through byte array using Glide?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I have an image contents byte[] form. But when i load them through Glide then broken images are shown. what I'm doing is shown below.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageByteArray)
    .asBitmap()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken)
    .into(rowImageView);
```

imageByteArray successfully converts to bitmap without using glide. So there is no wrong with image byte array.

Please guide me what I'm missing?

Also I'm using Glide library com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1
And Android support library com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1

**Edited**

Ok, This is what I'm doing.

```
String imageBytes = "HVao14fpmtHSev3OgsrQNsawkFzXNcY3BsfQla6..."
```

This string above defined is bytes of actual image which I'm receiving from web API.

I'm converting this String into byte array like this

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
}
```

Than I'm applying resultant byte array "imageByteArray" to Glide code defined above.

Comment: prolly, because you do not understand basics of multithreading ... but it is just blind guess ... as you did not provide how you obtain this byte array ... what is a scope of this variable is it used in some kind of loops ....

Comment: I do understand. Instead of giving these type of comments please guide me with proper answer. Thanks

Comment: then please ask the proper question ... as this code does provide  a NOT broken image form me (I used code from your question and libraries from the question)

Comment: It is written in the question that imageByteArray successfully converts to bitmap without using glide. for details, imageByteArray came from web API. which sends image in byte array

Comment: hehe "I do understand" ... no you don't ... => with "your understanding" of multithreading both examples (with and without glide) should have the same results:  http://ideone.com/7myeJE but as you can see thay has not ...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Lets say your base64 string is

```
String imageBytes = "HVao14fpmtHSev3OgsrQNsawkFzXNcY3BsfQla6..."
```

You should convert `imageBytes` String to array of bytes through

```
byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decode(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

afterwards pass this `imageByteArray` to Glide.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(imageByteArray)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken)
    .into(rowImageView);
```

Comment: @Andan Amjad I have this same issue , i tried this snippet, but showing error, can not resolve .asBitmap() , can you help me?

Comment: @AmitVerma which Glide version you are using? if it is below 5 then use .asBitmap() right after .with()

Comment: if I have list of images then this gets very slow

Comment: `.asBitmap()` what is that and why do we need it?

Comment: I tested without `.asBitmap()` and it works fine

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work if placeholder is not set, it seems to be a requirement to work.

Answer (score 14):

You can convert `Base64` String to image using the following

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(Base64.decode(base64ImageString, Base64.DEFAULT))
    .asBitmap()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken)
    .into(rowImageView);
```

Comment: what is different on your answer comparing to accepted one?!

Comment: Nothing, he just makes one less variable-

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin way:

```
val imageByteArray = Base64.decode(sampleBase64ImageString, Base64.DEFAULT)
Glide.with(this).load(imageByteArray).into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting error on `.asBitmap()` just use it like this

```
             Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageAsBytes)
                .into(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it a bit differently

```
byte[] bytes = Glide.with(context)
                        .as(byte[].class)
                        .load(url)
                        .submit()
                        .get();
```

The bytes are ready for file writing.

Answer (score 0):

Example of a Base 64 JPEG image

```
String dataImage = "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";
byte[] decodeDataImg = Base64.decode(dataImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeDataImg ,0, decodeDataImg .length);
Glide.with(view).load(bmp).into(imageView_example);
```

Tested code using Glide below version 5 but useful also in recent versions

```
dependencies { implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using compose:

```
byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

compose code:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = imageByteArray, contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.requiredSize(110.dp),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
)
```