# How to convert a bitmap or byte array to an image?

Tags: android, android-glide

My app, when user click capture button, start camera capture.

I use bitmap API. but sometimes memory problem.
so I want use `Glide` library.

current my source

```
//Run on Preview call from Camera
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, previewFormat, 640, 480, null);

  Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 640, 480);
  ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, bao); //Compress data in YUY2 format into a rectangular area in jpeg format.

  byte[] jpeg = bao.toByteArray();
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

  Bitmap convertedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length, options); //byte array to bitmap

  mCallback.imageTaken(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(convertedImage, 480, 360, true));
}
```

imageTaken(CaptureView.class)

```
   //completed capture picture.
   public void imageTaken(Bitmap bitmap) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

      displayImage(bitmap); //preview bitmap image.
   }
```

displayImage(CaptureView.class);

```
public class CaptureView extends View implements CaptureViewer {

   private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
   private Rect src = new Rect(120, 96, 342, 272);
   private Rect dst;
   private int viewWidth, viewHeight = 0;

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
      super.onMeasure(width, height);
      viewWidth = getLayoutParams().width;
      viewHeight = getLayoutParams().height;

      dst = new Rect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
   }

   @Override
   public void displayImage(Bitmap image) {
      if (mBitmap != null) {
          mBitmap.recycle();
      }
      mBitmap = null;
      mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
      postInvalidate();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, null);
  }
}
```

this source work, but I want use Glide library.
most of the examples, use url glide library.

but I want bitmap to image glide library.

How to convert a bitmap or byte array to an image using glide android?

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34702983/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar I check your link, but I don't know Where to place glide.

Comment: A bitmap is already an image. Or what do you mean exactly with an image?

Comment: @HemantParmar Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42278907/3111083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using below code you can get bitmap

```
Glide.with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(path)
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42278907/3111083)

```
     public void imageTaken(Bitmap bitmap) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

   Glide.with(this)
    .load(stream.toByteArray())
    .asBitmap()
    .error(R.drawable.ic_thumb_placeholder)
    .transform(new CircleTransform(this))
    .into(yourImageView); //preview bitmap image.
   }
```

Comment: I took it from your code. displayImage is your imageview in which you are trying to load image. See my edit.