# OutOfMemory error while loading Images using Sampling

Tags: android, android-glide, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am displaying `Images` on `RecyclerView` in `ImageView` with dimensions as `50*50`. I have used the guide [Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) given by google to display Bitmaps using Scaling etc.Along, with guide I have also use `Glide` library to set Image.The code to Sample Image is

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 2;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

This is a code to DecodeSampleBitmap

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(int reqWidth, int reqHeight,byte[] bytes) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inInputShareable=true;
        options.inPurgeable=true;
       // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,options);
        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,options);
    }
```

This is code to set Image to ImageView using Glide

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.length,options);
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                options.inInputShareable=true;
                options.inPurgeable=true;
                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                String imageType = options.outMimeType;
                Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),decodeSampledBitmap(50,50));
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .load(d).into(offerBinding.restImg);
```

In-spite of doing all this calculations I am always getting `OutOfMemory error` and app get crashed when more Images are load. How to resolve this ?

Comment: did you add `android:largeHeap="true"` in your application tag in the `manifest` ?

Comment: from where you are getting images? online or from internal storage?

Comment: Yes. I have added large heah to true in Manifest

Comment: I am getting Images From Server using Api call

Comment: like image url right?

Comment: No.Its a Base 64 String which I am converting to bitmap and then rendering.

Comment: Did you make `setHasStableIds(true);` in `RecyclerView.Adapter` anywhere?

Comment: How does it will optimize image OutOfMemory error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load image through byte array using Glide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588905/how-to-load-image-through-byte-array-using-glide)

Answer (score 0):

For your  `base64String` to `Imageview` use it like this

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT))
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // load at start
.error(R.drawable.imagenotfound) // in case of error
.override(50,50)  
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.into(rowImageView);
```

I Hope it will works fine

Comment: what about image scaling etc ?

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Comment: No. still the same Memory Issue