# Unable to load image from data Uri

Tags: android, android-glide, data-uri

I am receiving a data uri from a remote API using retrofit. I tried many methods yet not able to get the image set on the image view. Please help me in it.

```
[The data Uri starts with imagedata:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K6IkSfJ5fRAlSZLP64MoSZJ8Xh9ESZLk8/ogSpIkn9cHUZIk+bw+iJIkyef1QZQkST6vD6IkSfJ5fRAl.....]
```

I used the following code in my activity.

```
if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                QRcodeResponse qRcodeResponse= (QRcodeResponse) response.body();
                QRData data = qRcodeResponse.getData();
                String dataString = data.getQrCode().toString();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(dataString);
                Glide.with(My_qr_codeActivity.this)
                        .load(uri).into(Image_view_myQRcode);
                Log.i("QRCODE :", "The response QR image" + data.getQrCode().toString());
            }
```

Comment: Your image is encoded in base64. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview

Comment: I tried this method using Byte Code array, still was not getting any image for imageview

Comment: Yeah did you remove `imagedata:image/png;base64,` from the beginning of the base64 string before converting it to a byte array?

Comment: No I did not, do we need to remove it?

Comment: Yes or else its not a valid base64 and the decoded bytes will then contain that data and the image won't be valid

Comment: Hey, I think this link will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588905/how-to-load-image-through-byte-array-using-glid