# problem with sending byte[] images list to Glie

Tags: android-glide, mediametadataretriever

## Hello, good time everyone I'm making a music player and I'm having trouble getting the music image from the vote list I have been struggling with this for 3 days, if anyone has any information, please help me

```
#private byte[] getAlbumArt(String uri) {
        byte[] art;
        try {
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(uri);
            art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            retriever.release();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return art;

    }

  byte[] imageByteArray = getAlbumArt(songArrayList.get(position).getPath());

        if (imageByteArray!=null){
            GlideApp.with(context).load(imageByteArray).into(holder.imageView);
        }else {
            GlideApp.with(context).load(R.drawable.baseline_person_24).into(holder.imageView);
        }





# 
2023-04-28 14:12:47.945 23936-23987 ion                     com.memol.musicplayer                E  ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2023-04-28 14:12:47.945 23936-23987 skia                    com.memol.musicplayer                D  stream getLength() not supported, use temp buffer for loading stream, buffer addr 0x7dbd5f9000 length 121971
2023-04-28 14:12:47.945 23936-23987 skia                    com.memol.musicplayer                D  LoadInputStreamToMem va 0x7dbd5f9000  size 124160
2023-04-28 14:12:47.946  1067-1067  audit                   auditd                               E  type=1327 audit(1682678567.941:107898): proctitle="com.memol.musicplayer"
2023-04-28 14:12:47.946 23936-23987 libjpeg-alpha           com.memol.musicplayer                D  Huffman Builder run in subthread
2023-04-28 14:12:47.948 23936-23987 libjpeg-alpha           com.memol.musicplayer                D  Tile Decoder (#thread:4, size:512 256 256 256x320, alignment:256x16)
2023-04-28 14:12:47.949 23936-23988 libjpeg-alpha           com.memol.musicplayer                D  Corrupt JPEG data: 15161 extraneous bytes before marker 0xc4
2023-04-28 14:12:47.965 23936-23936 MediaMetadataRetriever  com.memol.musicplayer                V  setDataSource(103, 0, 576460752303423487)
2023-04-28 14:12:47.974 23936-23936 MediaMetadataRetriever  com.memol.musicplayer                V  setDataSource(fd) return(-2147483648)
2023-04-28 14:12:47.975 23936-23936 AndroidRuntime          com.memol.musicplayer                D  Shutting down VM
2023-04-28 14:12:47.982 23936-23936 AndroidRuntime          com.memol.musicplayer                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.memol.musicplayer, PID: 23936
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
                                                                                                        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:254)
```

Comment: stream getLength() not supported, use temp buffer for loading stream, buffer addr 0x7dbd5f9000 length 121971
                com.memol.musicplayer                D  LoadInputStreamToMem va 0x7dbd5f9000  size 124160

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588905/how-to-load-image-through-byte-array-using-glide This might be useful to you. Please check.